# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined while converting a list to a dynamic drop down

Tags: reactjs

I am working in converting a list of items into a dynamic dropdown option list but I have a problem.

I checked if the props are coming right and they are.

this is the piece of code that converts the list:

```
    buildSelectOptions = (opts) => {
        return opts.map((opt) =>  <Option value={opt.id}>{opt.uid}</Option>)
    };
    render() {
       const {allKeycodes} = this.props.allKeycodes; 
       console.log(allKeycodes);
       const allKeycodesOptions = this.buildSelectOptions(allKeycodes);
    }
```

I am sorry if anything is missing to understand the problem and I am ready to tell anything you need to understand this problem.

the error says: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

this is the complete code:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Modal, Tabs, Row, Col, Button, Alert, Select} from "antd";
import {saveAs} from "file-saver";
import JSZip from "jszip";
import styled from "styled-components";
import moment from "moment";
import TableComponent from "components/Shared/TableComponent";

import logo from "assets/images/homeKeyLogoSign.png";
import keycodesImage from "assets/images/Logo_HomeKey.png";
import keycodesImageBW from "assets/images/Homekey-bw.PNG";

const {TabPane} = Tabs;
const Option = Select.Option;

const StyledModal = styled(Modal)`
    input {
        height: 50px !important;
    }
    padding: 10px !important;
`;

const LeftPanel = styled.div`
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;  
`;

const StyledImg = styled.img`
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
`;

const Label = styled.p`
    margin:auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:0.9em;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    color: #858585;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
`;

const Title = styled.h1`
    color: #25B0FF;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 15px !important;
`;

const Value = styled.p`
    margin:auto;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size:1em;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
`;

const ScansBox = styled.div`
    margin:auto;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    min-height:20px;
    width:250px;
`;

const ScanLabel = styled.p`
    font-size:1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;

`;

const ScanValue = styled.h1`
    color: #25B0FF !important;
    font-size:4em;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold;
`;

const DefaultButton = styled(Button)`
    margin:auto;
    background: #25B0FF !important;
    color: white !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    padding: 0 40px !important;
    min-height: 50px;
    width:250px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    margin-top: 15px;
`;
const DefaultButtonWhite = styled(Button)`
    margin:auto;
    color: #25B0FF !important;
    font-weight: 300 !important;
    padding: 0 40px !important;
    min-height: 50px;
    width:250px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    border:1px solid #25B0FF !important;
`;

const StatusSection = styled.div`
    min-height:130px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius:10px;
`;

const StatusContent = styled.div`
    height:570px;
    background-color: #EEF2F6;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
`;

const ResidenceDetailsSection = styled.div`
    min-height:385px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius:10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
`;

const DetailsHeader = styled.h1`
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em
    color: #25B0FF !important;
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: bold;
`;

const StyledAlert = styled(Alert)`
    margin-bottom: 20px !important;
`;

const StyledSelectInput = styled(Select)`
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    .ant-select-selection--single {
         height: 50px !important;
    }
    .ant-select-selection__rendered {
        line-height: 50px !important;
    }
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
    min-width: 250px;
`;

const columns = [{
    title: "Date & Time",
    dataIndex: "scan.createdAt",
    key: "DateTime",
}, {
    title: "UserID",
    dataIndex: "device.userId",
    key: "UserID",
}, {
    title: "Version",
    dataIndex: "device.appVersion",
    key: "Version"
}, {
    title: "OS",
    dataIndex: "device.deviceOS",
    key: "OS",
}, {
    title: "Device",
    dataIndex: "device.deviceType",
    key: "Device",
}];

class HomeDetails extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loadingDownload: false,
            error: null
        };
        this.state = {assignKeycodeCkicked: false};
    }

    onTabsChange = (key) => {};

    formatStatus = (status) => {
        let formattedStatus = status.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + status.slice(1);
        return formattedStatus.replace(/[_-]/g, " ");
    };

    handleAssignKeycodesClick() {
        this.setState({assignKeycodeCkicked: 'true'});
    }

    downloadSvgAndPng = (keycodeUID) => {
        this.setState({loadingDownload: true});
        const zip = new JSZip();
        const requests = ['svg', 'png'].map((ext) => this.props.getKeycodeImage(keycodeUID, ext).then((response) => ({
            ext,
            file: response
        })));

        Promise.all(requests)
            .then((responses) => Promise.all(responses.map((response) => zip.file(`${keycodeUID}.${response.ext}`, response.file))))
            .then(() => zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"}))
            .then((zipFile) => {
                saveAs(zipFile, `keycode-${keycodeUID}-images.zip`);
                this.setState({loadingDownload: false});
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({loadingDownload: false, error: `No images found for keycode: ${keycodeUID}`})
            })
    };

    buildSelectOptions = (opts) => {
        return opts.map((opt) =>  <Option value={opt.id}>{opt.uid}</Option>)
    };

    selectFilterOptions = (input, option) => {
        return option.props.children.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    };

    render() {
        const data = this.props.data || {keycode: {}, builder: {}, community: {}, home: {}};
        const keyCodeScans = this.props.keycodeScans || {count: 0, scans: []};
        const lastKeycodeScan = keyCodeScans.scans[0] ? moment(keyCodeScans.scans[0].scan.createdAt).format("MMM DD, YYYY - HH:mm")  : "--";
        this.handleAssignKeycodesClick = this.handleAssignKeycodesClick.bind(this);
        const {allKeycodes} = this.props.allKeycodes;

        const allKeycodesOptions = this.buildSelectOptions(allKeycodes);
        const AssigneKeycode = this.state.assignKeycodeCkicked;
        console.log(allKeycodes)
        return (

            <StyledModal
                visible={this.props.visible}
                onOk={this.props.closeModal}
                onCancel={this.props.closeModal}
                footer={null}
                width={900}
                centered
            >
                <Tabs defaultActiveKey="tab-2" onChange={this.onTabsChange}>
                    <TabPane tab={<img alt="homeKeyLogo" src={logo}/>} disabled key="tab-1"/>
                    <TabPane tab="DETAILS" selected key="tab-2">
                        <Row>
                            {this.state.error && <StyledAlert message={this.state.error} type="error"/>}
                        </Row>
                        <Row>

                        {AssigneKeycode ? 
                            <Col span={8}>
                               <LeftPanel>
                                    <StyledImg className="logo" alt="homeKeyLogo" src={keycodesImageBW}/>
                                    <Title>Are you sure you want to assign a new KeyCode?</Title>
                                    <StyledSelectInput
                                        showSearch
                                        placeholder="Select a keycode id"
                                        optionFilterProp="children"
                                        >
                                    </StyledSelectInput>
                                    <DefaultButton>Assign new keycode</DefaultButton>
                                    <DefaultButtonWhite>cancel</DefaultButtonWhite>
                                </LeftPanel>
                            </Col>
                           :

                            <Col span={8}>
                                <LeftPanel>
                                    <StyledImg className="logo" alt="homeKeyLogo" src={keycodesImage}/>
                                    <Label>Keycode Id</Label>
                                    <Value>{data.keycode.uid}</Value>
                                    <Label>Batch</Label>
                                    <Value>{data.keycode.keycodeBatchId || "--"}</Value>
                                    <ScansBox>
                                        <ScanLabel>Total Scans</ScanLabel>
                                        <ScanValue>{keyCodeScans.count || 0}</ScanValue>
                                    </ScansBox>
                                    <DefaultButton onClick={() => this.downloadSvgAndPng(data.keycode.uid)} loading={this.state.loadingDownload}>Download Svg & Png</DefaultButton>
                                    <DefaultButton onClick={this.handleAssignKeycodesClick}>Assign New Keycode</DefaultButton>
                                </LeftPanel>
                            </Col> 
                        }
                            <Col span={16}>
                                <StatusContent>
                                    <Row>
                                        <StatusSection>
                                            <Col span={12}>
                                                <DetailsHeader>Status</DetailsHeader>
                                                <Label>Keycode assigned on</Label>
                                                <Value>{data.keycode.assignedAt ? moment(data.keycode.assignedAt).format("MMM DD, YYYY - HH:mm") : "--"}</Value>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col span={12}>
                                                <DetailsHeader>{data.keycode.status ?
                                                    this.formatStatus(data.keycode.status)
                                                    : "--"
                                            }</DetailsHeader>
                                                <Label>Last Scan</Label>
                                                <Value>{lastKeycodeScan}</Value>
                                            </Col>
                                        </StatusSection>
                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <ResidenceDetailsSection>
                                            <Row>
                                                <DetailsHeader>Residence Details</DetailsHeader>
                                                <Label>Address</Label>
                                                <Value>{data.home.fullAddress || "--"}</Value>
                                            </Row>
                                            <Col span={12}>
                                                <Label>Builder</Label>
                                                <Value>{data.builder.companyName}</Value>
                                                <Label>Residence Type</Label>
                                                <Value>{data.home.homeType}</Value>
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col span={12}>
                                                <Label>Community</Label>
                                                <Value>{data.community.name}</Value>
                                                <Label>Activated On</Label>
                                                <Value>{data.keycode.activatedAt || "--"}</Value>
                                            </Col>
                                        </ResidenceDetailsSection>
                                    </Row>
                                </StatusContent>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane tab="HISTORY" key="tab-3">
                        <Row>
                            <Col span={24}>
                                <TableComponent columns={columns}
                                                dataSource={keyCodeScans.scans}
                                                rowKey="id"
                                                loading={false}
                                                onChange={(page, size) => this.props.getKeycodeScans(data.keycode.id, page, size)}
                                                count={keyCodeScans.count}
                                />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </TabPane>
                </Tabs>
            </StyledModal>
        );
    }
}

export default HomeDetails;
```

the allKeycodes object from the console log:

````
(500) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
[0 … 99]
0: {id: 10, uid: "1000000000000010", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "unassigned", …}
1: {id: 9, uid: "1000000000000009", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "ready_to_ship", …}
2: {id: 8, uid: "1000000000000008", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "blank", …}
3: {id: 7, uid: "1000000000000007", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "ready_to_ship", …}
4: {id: 6, uid: "1000000000000006", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "installed", …}
5: {id: 5, uid: "1000000000000005", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "installed", …}
6: {id: 4, uid: "1000000000000004", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "activated", …}
7: {id: 3, uid: "1000000000000003", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "blank", …}
8: {id: 2, uid: "1000000000000002", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "unassigned", …}
9: {id: 1, uid: "1000000000000001", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "activated", …}
10: {id: 20, uid: "1000000000000020", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "ready_to_ship", …}
11: {id: 19, uid: "1000000000000019", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "assigned", …}
12: {id: 18, uid: "1000000000000018", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "installed", …}
13: {id: 17, uid: "1000000000000017", pngLocation: null, svgLocation: null, status: "blank", …}...```
````

Comment: Please show the code how you do the console.log

Comment: console.log(allKeycodes)

Comment: Hmmm interesting. Maybe can you update your question and include the logging statement?

Comment: i did it, added the statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are a couple of scenarios that can result in that error.

1) If your `this.props.allKeycodes` object doesn't have a `allKeycodes` property inside of it - `const {allKeycodes} = this.props.allKeycodes;` this will result in undefined, which then result in calling map on that undefined.

2) You can get that error, if you don't have a default value when you are passing props in your component/ or you don't check for undefined value. You can check it inside the function, or when calling the function, but it must not be undefined.

`buildSelectOptions = opts => opts && opts.map(....)` this code will check if `opts` isn't [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and run the next bit of code. Otherwise it will just result in `undefined`.

**UPDATE**

```
buildSelectOptions = (opts) => {
  return opts && opts.map((opt) =>  <Option value={opt.id}>{opt.uid}</Option>)
};
```

**OR**

```
buildSelectOptions = (opts) => {
    if(opts) {
      return opts.map((opt) =>  <Option value={opt.id}>{opt.uid}</Option>)
    }
};
```

Comment: the first statement does not stand and I stated in the question that data is coming as expected and the line of code is not resolving the problem

Comment: could you update the question with the structure of your `allKeycodes`?

Comment: that's the console.log of what ? `this.props.allKeycodes` or `allKeycodes` ?

Comment: and you've tried adding the opts check in the method ?

Comment: @EndritSheholli: Please share all the codes instead of trimming to almost nothing. Based on the code you written above, everything should be seems ok

Comment: but what else do you need, I am not using the list anywhere right now,

Comment: Do you have `undefined` in your console.log before or after it prints the array ?

Comment: So you see, you do get undefined first, that's where the error comes from. I've updated my answer with a check